# {"errors":[{"code":3,"message":"Invalid login details"}],"status":"failure"} in PHP By text local sms service

Tags: php, sms, codeigniter-3

```html
<?php
    // Account details
    $apiKey = urlencode('Your apiKey');
    
    // Message details
    $numbers = array(447123456789, 447987654321);
    $sender = urlencode('Jims Autos');
    $message = rawurlencode('This is your message');
 
    $numbers = implode(',', $numbers);
 
    // Prepare data for POST request
    $data = array('apikey' => $apiKey, 'numbers' => $numbers, "sender" => $sender, "message" => $message);
 
    // Send the POST request with cURL
    $ch = curl_init('https://api.txtlocal.com/send/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    
    // Process your response here
    echo $response;
?>
```

This Code is Not Working

Find this error

{"errors":[{"code":3,"message":"Invalid login details"}],"status":"failure"}

Comment: make sure your public ip is whitelisted in textlocal api keys section

Comment: Why would you need to `urlencode` your API key? I sincerely doubt any API generates a key that's not url safe.

Comment: If someone having the same issue, please check the textlocal url. I have the same issue and found out that the API documentation have the `https://api.txtlocal.com` and in my 
textlocal console it was `https://api.textlocal.in`.

Comment: thank you for your help. i already fix this issue